# Why is a type identifier followed by a function call?

Tags: c

I'm new to c, and this code confuses me:

```
pid_t getpid(void)
```

if what follows the type identifier `pid_t`is a variable (It's a variable declaration), but instead it's a function call `getpid()`, I don't know what why this function call is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that `pid_t` is a type identifier, but it's not a variable. `pid_t` is the return type of the function `getpid()`.

Every function in C has a return type. Functions are declared like this:
`returntype functionName(arguments)`

For example, `int main(int argc, const char * argv[])` returns an `int` and takes two arguments.

Comment: it makes sense, does this only indicate the return value of the expression for documentation use only? like in php function document,`int time(void)`, but in the actual code, we don't use the return type identifier,

Comment: Whether you use the return value depends on your program. But it's more than for documentation use only—it means that the function *will* return something of that type, which you can capture. For example, if you had written `$currentTime = time();` in your PHP, you're using the return value.

Comment: Parameter and return types in declarations tell the compiler how to convert arguments and values automatically, and issue warnings if they aren't compatible.

Comment: Got it, thanks. could you help me to check this test code that I try to cooperate getpid() function, https://gist.github.com/3269297

Comment: @Inspire48 I figure it out myself, I miss including some header file, which clang compiler do it for me, however throw the warning

Answer (score 1):

```
pid_t getpid(void)
```

this means the function named `getpid` doesn't take any parameters (as the argument list contains only `void`) and returns a value of type `pid_t` (so you were correct with the type specifier).

Any basic book/tutorial on C would give you this information, I recommend you work through some of this on your own to get the basics down.

This SO question might be helpful: [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, I'm now working on basics, is there any book you would recommend of c?

Comment: @yozloy  The classic book for C (though it's old) is the ["little white book" by K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) - see also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language). I haven't seen any recent C texts, so I can't recommend anything specific, but almost any of them would cover the basic topics. By the way, I also just saw some PDF versions of this book floating around, so you could get it that way too :) .. a visit to your local public/university library might help too, you can browse the books to find one you like.

Comment: @yozloy No one here started out knowing everything .. everyone was a noob one time or the other (though some forget that from time to time)